# outputing select statement result into file

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have an sql file that contains below script that is ran via isql. 
May I ask whats wrong with my output syntax? I am getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'output'"

Sybase ASE version is 15.7

```
select * from tempdb..M3_STI_extracts_checking
output to employee.txt format ASCII
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

isql offers the possibility to write the output into a file, if you set the option `-o` ([Utility Commands Reference](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35456.1570/html/ocspsunx/X33477.htm)).

---

*input.sql*

```sql
select * from tempdb..M3_STI_extracts_checking
go
```

---

```sh
isql -i input.sql -o employee.txt
```

`-J` sets the charset ([ASE 15.7 charsets](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0707/html/prjdbc0707/prjdbc070731.htm))

```sh
isql -i input.sql -o employee.txt -J ascii_7
```

Comment: thanks but I needed the filename to be dynamic since I have to append a date stamp into it.I have solved it already using this code 
`output_file=test_file_'date +%m%d%Y'
${PARAM} isql << EOF
select * from tempdb..M3_STI_extracts_checking
GO > ${output_file}
EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to workaround by passing the variable from a shell script.

*test.sh*

```
output_file=test_file_'date +%m%d%Y' 

${PARAM} isql << EOF 
select * from tempdb..M3_STI_extracts_checking 
GO > ${output_file} 
EOF
```